# How can I find a keyword in multiple string then print all of them in Python?

Tags: python

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def getyourfiles(ctx):
    """Prints all files that you uploaded"""
    ll = open('test2.txt', 'r').read()
    kk = str(ll)
    aa = kk.find(ctx.message.author.id)
    await bot.say(aa)
```

Test2 contains this:

```
140886965359738880 | XD3MPS.jpg
125367412370440192 | 28saa.png
140886965359738880 | 871AHA.jpg
125367412370440192 | 281aha.png
```

I need a way to post the 3rd and 1st one from a person's ID (which ctx.message.author.id gets and assuming the ID is the 1st and 3rd). I need to print both lines in as few code lines as possible. And the output of the program? 2. How do I print the strings themselves?

Edit: What I mean by "posting" is printing. I need to print these two lines from Test2:

```
140886965359738880 | XD3MPS.jpg
140886965359738880 | 871AHA.jpg
```

I would also like to point out that if I did run this program (it's a bot with different dependencies which should not affect how to answer the question), this program would spit out 2.

```
>>> ll = open('test2.txt', 'r').read()
>>> kk = str(ll)
>>> aa = kk.find('140886965359738880')
>>> print(aa)
... 2
```

Not exactly REPL, but close enough to understand the gist of it. 
These lines are what I need to end up as strings:

```
140886965359738880 | XD3MPS.jpg
140886965359738880 | 871AHA.jpg
```

Comment: What do you mean by "post" in "I need a way to post.."? You also say you need to "print both lines". By "post" do you mean just "print"? What is your question "and the output of the program?" referring to? Do you know what the output of the program is? Can you post the output for us to see? And by "print the strings themselves", which are the strings? Do you mean you want to parse the lines in the `test2.txt` file and print the first column of numbers? Please edit your question and try to clarify your questions more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be using regular expressions (`import re`)

The other (easier) option would be a list comprehension:

```
ll = open('test2.txt', 'r').readlines())
aa = [line for line in ll if line.startswith('140886965359738880')]
print aa
```

`readlines` gives a list of strings and equals to `readline().split('\n')`. The line beginning with `aa =` is a list comprehension. It filters every element of the list which fulfills the the `if` conditions, here that it begins with `'140886965359738880'`. `print aa` then prints the list. If you only want strings use

```
for element in aa:
    print element
```

instead.

---

Also consider using a context manager to read the file (or `try` `finally` to ensure to close the file afterwards:

```
with open('test2.txt', 'r') as file_:
    ll = file_.readlines()
```

ensures to close the file, even if an error occurs.

---

If you just want to iterate once over all matching lines consider using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. Just changes the brackets `[]` to `()`:

```
aa = (line for line in ll if line.startswith('140886965359738880'))
```

this returns an iterator instead of a list. It can be used to once loop over it (`for line in aa: print aa`) or you can use the `aa.next()` method to get the elements. This can be more efficient for very large lists.

---

How your code finally could look like:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def getyourfiles(ctx):
    """Prints all files that you uploaded"""
    with open('test2.txt', 'r') as file_:
        ll = file_.readlines()
    aa = [line for line in ll if ll.startswith(ctx.message.author.id)]
    for line in aa:
        await bot.say(line)
```